# Sa-Token and Spring Gateway Conflict

Tags: java, spring, token, gateway

Simultaneously using `Spring Gateway` and `Sa-Token` results in the service being unable to register with `Nacos`.

Removing either `Gateway` or `Sa-Token` allows the application to successfully register with `Nacos`. Has anyone encountered and resolved this issue?

Versions：

- java: 17
- spring-boot: 3.0.2
- spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery: 2022.0.0.0-RC
- spring-cloud: 2022.0.0-RC
- sa-token-reactor-spring-boot3-starter: 1.37.0

Removing the 'routes' section allows the application to register successfully, but the routing functionality is lost. What should I do?

my `application.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    nacos:
      discovery:
        group: vevss
        username: nacos
        password: nacos
        server-addr: 127.0.0.1:8848
        namespace: public
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      # Removing the following section allows successful service registration
      routes:
        - id: auth-service
          uri: lb://auth-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/login
            - Path=/auth/doc.html
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/auth/doc.html, /doc.html

        - id: user-service
        # others ...

sa-token:
  token-name: satoken
  timeout: 2592000
  active-timeout: -1
  is-concurrent: true
  is-share: true
  token-style: uuid
  is-log: false
```